# SQL Group By with limit and distinct - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my tables and structure

**Shoutbox**

- SID   //PK
- Title //Title

**shoutbox_follower**

- SID
- UID //User ID

**Shouts**

- SID
- Text //Shouts

I want to get the last 1 (latest) shouts(Shouts.Text) for each Shoutbox, which the user is following

---

i tried this but it did not worked

```
select shoutbox_follower.SID,shoutbox.title, shouts.text from shoutbox_follower, shoutbox, shouts where shoutbox_follower.uid=1;
```

But i can do the work with multiple query

```
SELECT SID from shoutBox_Follower where UID=5
SELECT SID,TEXT from Shouts where SID in ($boxList) order by id desc limit 1
SELECT Title from Shoutbox where SID=? limit 1
```

Comment: This kind of sql question is asked on SO at least weekly.

Comment: @zerkms perhaps it's the trend LOL :P

Comment: @Sourav: nope, it is lack of sql basics knowledge :-P `INNER JOIN` + subquery + `GROUP BY` + `MAX` --- this is what you need.

Comment: @zerkms you hurt me :( , i'm looking for a good performance query, and guys on SO have better knowledge on query optimization than i have :)

Comment: If you need really **performant** solution - then keep the reference to the latest shout per each shoutbox and maintain that with triggers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine the queries, in cases like this:

```
SELECT SID,
       (select TEXT
       from Shouts
       where Shouts.SID = shoutBox_Follower.SID
       order by Shouts.SID desc limit 1
       ) as shout_text
from shoutBox_Follower
where UID=5
```

It performs very fast for small numbers of rows (assuming you've the needed indexes, of course). Based on your third query, the title can be fetched using a simple inner join.

Comment: Subquery will be executed N times here.

Comment: Indeed it will, and that's the whole point: a handful of index scans will perform better than an enormous merge join. Plus, that's what basically he's doing already... :-)

Answer (score 1):

In comments you mentioned that you need **fast** solution. If so - then add a field `latest_shout_id` to the `shoutbox` table and maintain it with `AFTER INSERT` trigger of `shouts` table. That's all.

Here is the query that will do what you want (assuming you have `shout_id` as a PK in `shouts` table and reference to `shoutbox` by `shoutbox_id` field):

```
    SELECT x.*
      FROM shoutbox_follower f
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(shout_id) shout_id,
                   shoutbox_id
              FROM Shouts s
          GROUP BY shoutbox_id) x ON x.shoutbox_id = f.sid 
     WHERE f.uid = 5
```

Changing it to correlated subquery may change it in faster or slower manner, it depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: thats a clever solution [+1] but i want to keep the DB  at minimal

Comment: @Sourav: so either you want to keep db as-is or get **fast** solution. Choose one.

Comment: Priority high `keep db as-is`, priority low `fast solution`

Comment: "i'm looking for a good performance query" --- so you deceived me :-(

Comment: Plus, re performance, this actually is the slowest possibility. The planner will join two entire tables together.

Comment: @Denis: not sure. Optimizer will evaluate uncorrelated subquery at first, after that optimizer will decide in what oder to join the tables (virtual one returned by subquery or real one). So I wouldn't predict the actual explain, since it depends on cardinality and data size at least. Also - index over `uid` (or probably `uid+sid`) will help alot

Comment: Well, I would dare doing so. Because `GROUP BY shoutbox_id) x ON x.shoutbox_id = f.sid` will not reinject the f.sid clause into the subquery. It'll then grab the whole thing for the whole table, irrespective of the fact that we need a few (a single?) row. This will usually lead to an enormous sort + merge join.

Comment: Yeyeye, but you can't make it correlated at that level. And it won't inject the outer variables into the subquery to extract only a few rows, which is why I added my initial comment. I'm not saying your solution is incorrect, btw. I'm merely pointing out how the planner will react in this situation. I've seen this kind of plan lead to joining millions of rows together, only to extract one or two; it's not pretty.

Comment: @Denis: yep, you're right. Anyway, in real life I just denormalize schema and query everything in one trivial query ;-)

Comment: i love zerkms's idea on adding a new attribute 'LastShoutID'